# Как вставить в шаблон регулярного выражения обратный слеш?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

Вирусописатели в очередной раз прислали сотрудникам архив со скриптом на Javascript. Там по хитрому собиратется какой-то адрес из обычных символов и символов в acsii (пример `\x65`).

Так как изучаю Python хотел заменить эти ascii-символы на обычные прямо в тексте и потом собрать в адрес. Пытаясь определить ascii-символы через регулярное выражение наткнулся на такое что не могу написать обратный слеш в выражении. двойной обратный слеш дает два слеша а не один как рассчитывал.
Подскажите написание регулярного выражения для строки вида `"\x65"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://ideone.com/fGi24c

```
import re

s = input()
match = re.search('\\\\x\d\d', s, re.IGNORECASE)
print(match)
```

Comment: Почему в match попадают два обратных слеша? В вашем примере в строке для поиска он всего один.

Comment: @plmax, вроде в соседнем ответе уже объяснили.

Comment: Мне нужно получить подстроку с одним слешем.

Comment: @plmax, так я с одним и получил.

Comment: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(12, 16), match='\\x65'>
в выводе как и в регулярных выражениях два слеша считать за один?

Comment: @plmax, в исходной строке сколько слешей? Очевидно, что в найденной столько же.

Comment: Я не понимаю ответа вопросом на вопрос. В исходной строке один слеш.

Comment: @plmax, читай соседний ответ.

Comment: Разобрался. Когда выводишь список найденных подстрок то элементы списка выводятся в виде '\\x65'. А когда начинаешь использовать каждый элемент отдельно то он выводится как '\x65'. Спасибо.

Answer (score 5):

Обратный слеш в регулярных выражениях - *так как в них он имеет специальное значение* - нужно писать как пару обратные слешов - `\\`.

Но *Питон сам* использует в обычных строковых литералах обратный слеш *для специяльных символов*, например символа перехода на новую строку `\n`. Потому в обычных строковых литералах Питона нужно писать обратный слеш тоже как пару обратных слешов - `\\`. В итоге для 2 обратных слешов нужно их писать 4: `"\\\\"`

Но возможный тоже другой - лучший подход. Литералы с буквой `r` непосредственно перед открывающим апострофом или кавычкой понимает Питон буквенно, не интерпретируя их.

В итоге у вас 2 подхода, как перенести из Питона в регулярное выражение нужные 2 обратные слеши:

1. Написать 4 обратные слеши: `"\\\\"` - Питон будет каждую пару слешов интерпретировать как один, или
2. Написать 2 обратные слеши, но начать строку с буквой `r`: `r"\\"`.